# Is it possible to dynamically create components in Angular7?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have this use case: I have to generate an HTML template depending on a template type selected by the user. The HTML inside the two templates are dynamic. I mean, it has to receive some data to be completed.

I work with Angular 7, TypeScript and C# so here is my code snippet (I have no clue how to start) and I don't know if it's possible to do so with Angular 7.

So, I have my the MainComponent, Template1Component, Template2Component.

Once user select the template type, he press on the GENERATE button and trigger the getPDF() method:

```
getPDF(selectedTemplateType: number) {
  let html = '';
  if (selectedTemplateType === 1) {
    // Fetch Template1Component 
    html = Template1Component.BuildHtml(someData);
  } else {
    // Fetch Template2Component
    html = Template2Component.BuildHtml(someData);
  }
  // this is the part I need, the rest of the code is already done.
}
```

Need help to do this part of code.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader